# Extract a sub-tree from a hierarchy tree based on a leaf in Oracle

Tags: oracle, tree, hierarchical-data, connect-by

I have a table `users` representing a hierarchical tree like this:

| Column | Type | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user_id | integer | sequence |
| user_type | integer | 1 for group of users 2 for normal user |
| group_id | integer | Reference to a user in the same table with user_type = 1 |
| user_name | varchar(xxx) |  |

The group_id column references another user_id so that groups and users are stored in the same table.

The  master group_id is 0.

Like this:

| user_id | user_type | group_id | user_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | null | 'All users' |
| 5 | 2 | 0 | 'USER1' |
| 6 | 2 | 0 | 'USER2' |
| 11 | 1 | 0 | 'SUBGROUP1' |
| 12 | 1 | 11 | 'SUBGROUP2' |
| 13 | 2 | 12 | 'USER3' |
| 20 | 1 | 0 | 'SUBGROUP3' |
| 21 | 2 | 20 | 'USER4' |

Notice that:

- There can be gaps in user_id.
- A group can contain nothing or any number of groups or users.

I have already managed to retrieve the full tree, properly indented and sorted, by using the `connect by` oracle statement.

This is not my question here.

My question is:

Given a user_id to a query, how to browse the tree up to the master group 'All Users'
and output as a result the full path from the leaf to the master group ?

**Example 1: I run the query for USER1, i want the following output:**

```
All Users
- USER1
```

**Example 2: I run the same query for USER3, i want the following output:**

```
All Users
- SUBGROUP1
-- SUBGROUP2
--- USER3
```

I hope someone could help me on this.

For information i post the query to retrieve the full tree, for you to see the use of `connect by` and `start with`.
I'm sure this query is close to the one i want, but my tries never produce the result i want.

```
select 
  lpad('-', (level - 1) * 2, ' ') || u.user_name as padded_name, 
  u.userid, 
  u.user_group, 
  u.user_type,
  level
from users u
connect by prior u.user_id = u.group_id
start with u.user_id = 0
order siblings by upper(u.user_name);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `connect by` to walk in the opposite direction. Then the `level` will of course be opposite too. So to get the results in the right order and indentation, chain another query based on these results that will use `row_number()` to determine the indentation:

```
with base as (
  select 
    u.user_name,
    u.user_id, 
    u.group_id, 
    u.user_type,
    level as lvl
  from users u
  connect by prior u.group_id = u.user_id
  start with u.user_id = 13
)
select 
  lpad('-', (row_number() over (order by lvl desc) - 1) * 2, ' ') || base.user_name
    as padded_name,
  user_id,
  group_id,
  user_type
from base
order by lvl desc;
```